# Differential Algebraic Equation Question

Tags: differential-algebraic-equations

This isn't a homework question, just something I'm trying to learn.

> Consider the differential equation $\dot{y}=f(y)$ with known invariants $g(y)=$ Const , and assume that $g^{\prime}(y)$ has full rank. Prove by differentiation of the constraints that, for initial values satisfying $g\left(y_{0}\right)=0$, the solution of the differential-algebraic equation (DAE)
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \dot{y} &=f(y)+g^{\prime}(y)^{T} \mu \\
> 0 &=g(y)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> also solves the differential equation $\dot{y}=f(y)$.

I can't for the life of me understand how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Background: I'm taking a differential equations class. For a project we need to choose to implement something. I'm interested in dimensionality reduction so I decided to implement the algorithm in [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/050639703). This involves solving a differential equation on the manifold of unitary matrices. I was reading background about how to do that in [this textbook](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540306634) which is where I got this question from.

Comment: Thanks for you edit.  It really does make a difference, and folks are much more likely to take an interest in your question, when you add background, thoughts, and such.